# Tomcat ECDHE-ECDSA chiphers are not supported

Tags: ssl, openssl, tomcat7

Tomcat does not support ECDHE-ECDSA* ciphers. Configuration and version information is given below.

- OS is CentOS 6.5 x64
- Tomcat version is 7.0.56 Tomcat native version is 1.1.30 (Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library 1.1.30 using APR version 1.3.9.)
- Java is Oracle jdk1.8.0_20

SSL config in Tomcat server.conf:

```
SSLHonorCipherOrder="true" SSLDisableCompression="true"
SSLCipherSuite="ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-RC4-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA38:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES256-SHA256:AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:AES128-SHA:RC4-SHA:RC4-MD5"
```

But [sslscan](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sslscan/) script displays as ECDHE-ECDSA* ciphers as "Failed"

```
Failed    SSLv3  256 bits  ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Failed    SSLv3  256 bits  ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384
```

[SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/) site also does display ECDHE-ECDSA* ciphers.

I know the mentioned bug record here https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55915 it is closed-fixed (and verified)

sslscan script with the above configured SSLCipherSuite returns only the following ciphers as accepted.

```
Accepted  SSLv3  256 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
Accepted  SSLv3  256 bits  AES256-SHA
Accepted  SSLv3  128 bits  ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA
Accepted  SSLv3  128 bits  AES128-SHA
Accepted  SSLv3  128 bits  DES-CBC3-SHA
Accepted  SSLv3  128 bits  ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA
Accepted  SSLv3  128 bits  RC4-SHA
Accepted  SSLv3  128 bits  RC4-MD5
Accepted  TLSv1  256 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
Accepted  TLSv1  256 bits  AES256-SHA
Accepted  TLSv1  128 bits  ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA
Accepted  TLSv1  128 bits  AES128-SHA
Accepted  TLSv1  128 bits  DES-CBC3-SHA
Accepted  TLSv1  128 bits  ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA
Accepted  TLSv1  128 bits  RC4-SHA
Accepted  TLSv1  128 bits  RC4-MD5
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: (Late but) Do you have an ECDSA (ECC signing) cert and key configured? You obviously have an RSA cert&key because of the ciphers that succeeded, and AFAIK Tomcat/APR cannot configure multiple cert&key (although the underlying OpenSSL could support it).

Answer (score -1):

I think its not for tomcat server.

(This cipher names are for ms servers).

In tomcat cipher using underscores(_) not hyphen(-).

[Check this link](https://serverfault.com/questions/693422/warning-none-of-the-ciphers-specified-are-supported-by-the-ssl-engine)