# WARNING: None of the ciphers specified are supported by the SSL engine

Tags: ssl, tomcat, tls, tomcat7

I have a working web service running through `Apache Tomcat 7` with the following connector element in `server.xml`:

```
<Connector port="443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol" 
 SSLEnabled="true" 
 maxThreads="150"
 scheme="https" 
 secure="true" 
 clientAuth="false"  
 keystoreFile="C:\Java\myhost.keystore" 
 keystorePass="importkey" 
 sslProtocol="TLS"
/>
```

This has been working fine for years, but now a new `Logjam` security threat emerged, and I am trying to secure my web service, using the [Guide to Deploying Diffie-Hellman for TLS](https://weakdh.org/sysadmin.html) instructions.

So, I added the following line to the `<connector>` element:

> ciphers="ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256, ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256,
>   ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384,
>   DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256,
>   DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA,
>   ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA, DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256, DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA,
>   DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256, DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256, DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA,
>   DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA, AES128-GCM-SHA256, AES256-GCM-SHA384,
>   AES128-SHA256, AES256-SHA256, AES128-SHA, AES256-SHA, AES, CAMELLIA,
>   DES-CBC3-SHA"

Tomcat restarts fine, but I am no longer able to connect to my web service.

Upon examining the log, I noticed this line:

> WARNING: None of the ciphers specified are supported by the SSL engine
>   : ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256, ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256,
>   ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384,
>   DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256,
>   DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA,
>   ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA, DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256, DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA,
>   DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256, DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256, DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA,
>   DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA, AES128-GCM-SHA256, AES256-GCM-SHA384,
>   AES128-SHA256, AES256-SHA256, AES128-SHA, AES256-SHA, AES, CAMELLIA,
>   DES-CBC3-SHA

What am I missing in trying to get Tomcat use only these ciphers?

How do I make them supported by the SSL engine?

Comment: Not sure if it matters, but you may change `sslProtocol` directive to this `sslProtocols = "TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2"` ad then try `ciphers="TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA"`

Comment: @krisFR Thank you. I just tried your suggestion and this one failed even harder: `java.io.IOException: TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2 SSLContext not available`. I am still at a loss. Any tip would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: @krisFR I just tried your ciphers chain again, but this time with `sslProtocols = "TLS"` only and **it works!** Please post your comment (with my correction) as an answer so that I can accept it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As explained [here](https://blog.eveoh.nl/2014/02/tls-ssl-ciphers-pfs-tomcat/) you may have to set the `ciphers` list like this :

```
sslProtocols = "TLS"
ciphers="TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA,
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_25‌​6_CBC_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA"
```

> The first part, ECDHE, specifies what key exchange algorithm should be
>   used.
>   [...]
>
> Next up is the authentication algorithm, RSA. [...]
>
> The bulk cipher, AES128-GCM is the main encryption algorithm and used to
>   encrypt all the traffic. [...]
>
> The last part, SHA256, identifies the
>   message digest in use, which verifies the authenticity of messages.